# Dynamic Predicate for Selecting Different Columns of an Entity

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity, predicate

I have a requirement to showing all or less properties of an entity in the grid based on the page mode user select. For example I have three page modes

```
Minimal (will show 8 properties of an entity in the grid)

Standard (will show 12 properties of an entity in the grid)

Extended (will show 15 properties of an entity in the grid)
```

How can I make Select predicate dynamic to include the specified no of columns of an entity based on user page mode. Lets say I have Entity company with 15 properties I want to do something like this

```
dbContext.Companies.Select([predicate for choosing different no of columns?])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot solve this using [Predicates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx), because they always return `bool`.

What you need is a function expression that takes a `Company` object as a parameter and returns an `object`. Concretely, you need an `Expression<Func<Company, object>>`.

This is how you can define the three types of selection:

```
Expression<Func<Company, object>> minimal = e => new { e.Prop1, ..., e.Prop8 };
Expression<Func<Company, object>> standard = e => new { e.Prop1, ..., e.Prop12 };
Expression<Func<Company, object>> extended = e => new { e.Prop1, ..., e.Prop15 };
```

and then use them as you wish:

```
dbContext.Companies.Select(minimal);
// or
dbContext.Companies.Select(standard);
// or
dbContext.Companies.Select(extended);
```

Comment: Thanks wolf for this solution but I have a question here. I have an admin section where admin select which properties/columns to show on the main page. So I am getting a string array of 8, 12 or 15 columns how I will add those columns in the above solution.

Comment: @Waqas I've attempted to do this in several ways, but haven't succeeded so far. I think the solution would be to build an expression that populates a dynamic object with the entity's properties, but don't know how to do it or if it's even possible. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3591820/390819) gave me hope, but I still need to dig further.

Comment: Thanks @wolf, I also find this link may be it helps you too.


http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: @Waqas Nice link, but I think it's only about building predicates (functions that return bool and can be used in LINQ filters). I don't know if it helps with building the `select` list.