# Parse lamda and Invoke it with unknown type

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

We are using Lamda expression and Dynamic Invoke functionality to perform runtime queries on data objects. below is a sample code.

```
Class Person{
      string Id{get;set;}
}

Class Testclass{

    public void querydata(Person person)

     {
       var parm=Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person),"Person")
       string expression="Person.Id==\"1234\"";
       var e=DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] {parm},null,expression);
       bool response= (bool)e.Compile().DynamicInvoke(person);
     }
}
```

above function works just fine but we are trying to build generic System where consumer can pass their data object(like Person in above case but we do not know the actual type of it. we will get it as JSON/XML etc..) and expression and system has to perform runtime validation and do some logic depending on result.

Below is the pseudo code:

```
[Httppost]

Public someResponse runtimeValidation(JObject complexdataobject, string expression)
{
      var parm=Expression.Parameter(typeof(JObject),"Person")
           string expression="Person.Id==\"1234\"";
           var e=DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] {parm},null,expression);
           bool response= (bool)e.Compile().DynamicInvoke(person);
}
```

when i run above i'm getting "No Property Id exist in Type JObject".

I have been researching to find a way to create expression Parameter with unknown type but able to figure it out how to do..

Could you please guide me!!

Comment: Are they passing the actual data objects (like the definition of Person), or just the expression referring to them? It might help to see an example of everything the consumer might pass.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN I have included sample snippet that I'm trying to create. basically, we will be receiving Json Tree of the object that consumer passing but we do not the definition.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944137/expression-trees-with-dynamic-parameter